# How to select an option in multiple select box and load data from selected option

Tags: html, drop-down-menu

I am trying to figure out how to load data from a selected option.
For example, in the multiselect dropdown box I have 3 options:

```
Option 1: Apple
Option 2: Orange
Option 3: Pear
```

Let's say I have a data list for each option. For example when I choose Apple,
It will load a table in an inner div describing its price, weight and country on the first column.

When I choose the 2nd option, it will allow me to compare it with the 1st option. It should load on the 2nd column.
For example:

```
Option  :   Apple  | Orange
Price   :   $3.95  | $2.50
Weight  :   40g    | 50g
Country :   USA    | Brazil
```

Would be great to know what the ideal language/method is for this?
JavaScript / jQuery ?

Edit : Sorry if there's any confusion, my main question was how to do what I just described?

Comment: You definitely need javascript for that. jQuery is highly recommended.

Comment: Thanks, do you know of any similar examples that can give me a headstart in the loading part?

Answer (score 0):

I would highly recommend that you use [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) for this. Among other things, jQuery has [excellent documentation](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page).

Comment: OK, but I don't have a good understanding of writing jQuery and I don't really do front-end. Having an example would help me greatly. Thanks.